# How to open new win form in same location as previous win form C#

Tags: c#, forms

I'm trying to get a Win Form application to open in the same location as the previous form. The only half way solution I have found so far is to set the StartPosition to CenterScreen; however, would like the new form to actually open where the previous form left off.

Here is the code that I have tried to do this with.

```cs
Form1 F1 = new Form1();
this.Hide();
F1.ShowDialog();

F1.Left = this.Left;
F1.Top = this.Top;
F1.Size = this.Size;

this.Close();
```

Comment: have you tried setting F1.Location = this.Location after it appeared?

Comment: Make a `Screen` Object, get the potion of the form from on screen and save it in a dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could grab the [Location](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159414(v=vs.110).aspx) of the form you are hiding and use it to set the location of the new form. But if you want that this location is considered by the WinForms engine you need to set the [StartPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition(v=vs.110).aspx) property to **FormStartPosition.Manual**

```
// Current form
Form f1 = new Form();
f1.Show();
Application.DoEvents();
Thread.Sleep(5000);

f1.Hide();
Form f2 = new Form();
f2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
f2.Location = f1.Location;
f2.Size = f1.Size;
f2.ShowDialog();
```

By the way, in your code, setting the properties Top,Left and Size AFTER the call to ShowDialog is useless because ShowDialog is modal and doesn't return until you close the form you have opened with ShowDialog, so you apply these properties to a closed form

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment @Steve. This really helped me resolve the issue.

Comment: Yeah, sliding the ShowDialog after the position statement fixed it. Appreciate you letting me know that once the ShowDialog statement has been called it doesn't matter what is after it.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I've run into this before. Try the below code and let me know if it works out for you:

`yourNewForm.Location = new Point(this.Left, this.Top);`

or if the calling form still exists this is even easier:

`yourNewForm.Location = this.Location;`

Comment: Yeah this is another way to place where the location is; however, the part I was getting caught up on was having the F1.ShowDialog to soon.

Comment: The thing I mentioned in my comment (but deleted lol)? So you have it working now?

Comment: Yeah, I got it working properly now. Thanks for showing another way of coding it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add new constructor with property System.Drawing.Point in Next Form, and by initializing Next Form object in previous form, you can pass location point like:

In Previous Form:

```
NextForm obj = new NextForm(this.Location);
```

In Next Form Constructor:

```
public NextForm(System.Drawing.Point location)
{
   this.Location = location;
}
```

P.S.
**Dont forget to add InitializeComponent() method in new constructor.**